# Rspec - bypass strategy on Chewy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, chewy-gem

[Chewy documentation](https://github.com/toptal/chewy) recommend set up the `:bypass` strategy for tests, with:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    Chewy.strategy(:bypass)
  end
end
```

But I get a:

```
undefined method `strategy' for Chewy:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Here my `spec_helper.rb`

```
require 'devise'
require 'support/controller_macros'
require 'chewy/rspec'


RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    Chewy.strategy(:bypass)
  end

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller

 end
```

Any suggestion here ?

Thanks in advance

**chewy version: 0.6.2**

**rails version: 4.1.7**

**rspec version: 3.1.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like bypass wasn't added until version 0.7.0. You're looking at documentation for a later version. If you click on the dropdown on github and select tags and select your version you'll see there's no mention of strategy.

https://github.com/toptal/chewy/blob/v0.7.0/lib/chewy/strategy/bypass.rb